# Polling a URL with setTimeout without delaying first poll

Tags: javascript, jquery, polling

I'm using the code snippet found here (http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery):

```
(function poll(){
   setTimeout(function(){
      $.ajax({ url: "server", success: function(data){
        //Update your dashboard gauge
        salesGauge.setValue(data.value);

        //Setup the next poll recursively
        poll();
      }, dataType: "json"});
  }, 30000);
})();
```

to poll a local URL on a frequent basis to check the status of a record. However I also want to execute the poll immediately after page load whereas the above snippet initiates a loop which only first fires after the timeout period (30 secs in this case).

How can I modify the above to poll immediatley and then subsequently every 30 seconds. :)

TIA!

Comment: Pull the anonymous function out of the setTimeout and put it into a named function. Call it immediately, and call it in the timeout.

Comment: Use a named function, call it, then register your intervall doesn't for for you?

Comment: Oh yeah, setInterval. I always forget about that one. I so rarely have any need for it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your insight Matías. I don't need you, you don't have to answer the question but constructive feedback is always more helpful to those who are learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just move your settimeout

```
(function poll(){       
      $.ajax({ url: "server", success: function(data){
        //Update your dashboard gauge
        salesGauge.setValue(data.value);
        setTimeout(poll, 30000);            
      }, dataType: "json"});      
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for the constructive response. Some of us are still learning and can't always see the wood for the trees.